# Apple wallet add as default card screen frozen (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, wallet, apple-wallet

I have an add to apple wallet button in my flutter mobile app to add a debit card from the app to the user's apple wallet. When you add it to the wallet it works fine, then it immediately asks you if you want to use the card as your Default Card (apple does this, not me). If you click the blue Add as default card button then behind the scenes it successfully adds the card as your default card in apple wallet except the button just freezes on the screen once you click it. I expect the add to wallet screen to disappear once this button is hit, how can I make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: You should really add some detail of what you have tried so far. A question like this one will not find an answer.

Comment: hi, how you add this button ? I could not find any documentation how to archive that. can you help me?